# Simultaneously losing internet on multiple machines

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet

For a while now I've encountered an issue where 3 of my machines running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS will lose connection simultaneously and never reconnect until I unplug and reconnect the ethernet cable. This has happened perhaps 50 times in the last 6 months - sometimes I recorded it happening after 3 days, sometimes 7, once it was 8... very random but the disconnection is always simultaneous.

They are all connected to the same switch/router/internet connection as the other machines I have running Windows 10, yet those have never had internet issues.

I tried updating 1 machine to 20.04.4 LTS, and moving another machine to a different room with a different switch/router/internet connection, but neither of these actions made any changes. What are your thoughts on this? Is there something I've missed?  For system specs, see below:

Machine 1: Intel Core i5-10400F with 16 GB DDR4

Machine 2: Intel Core i9-10850K with 32 GB DDR4

Machine 3: Intel Core i5-6600K with 8 GB DDR4

Comment: Note the time of a connectivity loss. What do your logs say around that time?

Comment: Also check your routers log. You might be dos'ing yourself. Look for SYN/ACK and ARP notices in logs (Ubuntu and router log).

Answer (score 1):

Perform a few tests in the state where the defect you describe becomes apparent. The test results will help you decide what the cause is.

Are you using IPv4, IPv6, or both at the same time? It's important to know this because according to the protocol, you then focus your tests. In some tests below, I will first give a command for the IPv4 and below it for the IPv6.

### IP address

```
ip addr
```

Make sure that the devices have a valid address and their interface has a `UP` flag.

### Routing table

```
ip route
ip -6 route
```

Each row is a single routing rule. There should be a default gateway among them.

### Network neighbors

```
ip neigh
ip -4 neigh
ip -6 neigh
```

The list must contain valid entries with the addresses of available neighbors.
Mandatory, the IP address of the default gateway should be among them.

If the list is empty or does not have neighbors with the 'REACHABLE' flag, attempt to communicate on the network by pinging known targets on the LAN and then repeat the `ip neigh` command.

### Physical interface state

```
sudo ethtool eth0
```

Replace the `eth0` name with the real name of the interface detected by the command `ip a` at the top.

Example of command output:

```
...
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

Pay attention to these lines:

```
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    ...
    Link detected: yes
```

- The link must be `yes`.
- The speed should be `1000Mb/s` or `100Mb/s` in case of very old switches. The new networks have a speed of `10000Mb/s`. This is also a good figure. :-)
- The duplex must be `Full`.

### DNS

```
dig www.google.com
```

Perform another test if neighboring servers respond to ping during a glitch, but targets specified by name on the Internet are not available.

The command will show you the address of the DNS server and also how name-to-address resolution works.

### Other possible causes

- Security issue #1, 802.1x. If the 802.1x authentication is used on the network, a problem may occur on the port when the server certificate is faulty or expired. Until a new certificate is obtained, the port is disconnected or the server is quarantined.
- The `Error disabled` status of switch port. This can occur when the switch evaluates the communication on the port as defective, e.g. port flapping etc.
- Security issue #2, the ARP inspection, DHCP snooping. Too many ARP broadcasts on the switch port or several addresses on the port where a single one is expected.